# Error reading Excel using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel

i have this code to read Excel file

```
    Dim scheduleFileName As String

    'Creating Excel Object
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = "E:\Vb Deployment\scheduling\scheduleSheet.xlsx"

    Dim objExcel As New Excel._ExcelApplication
    Dim objWrkBk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim testdata As String

    objWrkBk = GetObject(fileName)
    ' or objWrkBk = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xls")
    objSht = objWrkBk.Worksheets(0)

    testdata = objSht.Cells(1, 1).Value.ToString()
```

But it give at error on line

```
objSht = objWrkBk.Worksheets(0)
```

Error: member not found....

Could you please let me know why I am getting this error and how I could correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Workbook` does have a member [`Worksheets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.worksheets%28VS.80%29.aspx). The only thing that's missing is the typecast

```
objSht = CType(objWrkBk.Worksheets(0),  Excel.Worksheet)
```